# How to avoid so many indexing in the code - python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am new to python and I feel like I am using the absolutely wrong strategy for programming in python. Here is an example:

I have a list like this:

```
selected_parents = 
[array([[4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 2]]), array([[0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6]])]
```

Now I want to apply crossover to the elements of the list (please see the **P.S.** for what I mean by crossover and how it is done, but again, my question is how I should avoid so many indexing that I use while programming in python):

```
crossed_p1 = np.zeros((len(selected_parents[0][0]))).astype(int)
crossed_p2 = np.zeros((len(selected_parents[0][0]))).astype(int)

co_point = rd.sample(range(len(selected_parents[0][0])),1)

if co_point[0] >= len(selected_parents[0][0])/2:
        crossed_p1[0:co_point[0]] = selected_parents[0][0][0:co_point[0]]

        indeces = []
        for i in range(co_point[0],len(selected_parents[0][0])):
            a = np.where(selected_parents[1][0] == selected_parents[0][0][i])
            indeces.append(a)
            indeces = sorted(indeces)

        for i in range(len(indeces)):
            crossed_p1[i + co_point[0]] = selected_parents[1][0][indeces[i][0][0]]

        crossed_p2[0:co_point[0]] = selected_parents[1][0][0:co_point[0]]

        indeces = []
        for i in range(co_point[0],len(selected_parents[0][0])):
            a = np.where(selected_parents[0][0] == selected_parents[1][0][i])
            indeces.append(a)
            indeces = sorted(indeces)

        for i in range(len(indeces)):
            crossed_p2[i + co_point[0]] = selected_parents[0][0][indeces[i][0][0]]

    else:
        crossed_p1[co_point[0]:] = selected_parents[0][0][co_point[0]:]

        indeces = []
        for i in range(co_point[0]):
            a = np.where(selected_parents[1][0] == selected_parents[0][0][i])
            indeces.append(a)
            indeces = sorted(indeces)

        for i in range(len(indeces)):
            crossed_p1[i] = selected_parents[1][0][indeces[i][0][0]]

        crossed_p2[co_point[0]:] = selected_parents[1][0][co_point[0]:]

        indeces = []
        for i in range(co_point[0]):
            a = np.where(selected_parents[0][0] == selected_parents[1][0][i])
            indeces.append(a)
            indeces = sorted(indeces)

        for i in range(len(indeces)):
            crossed_p2[i] = selected_parents[0][0][indeces[i][0][0]]
```

The code works like a charm, but I hate the way I am writing it! Like I keep questioning myself, do I really have to write something like `selected_parents[0][0][indeces[i][0][0]]`?! Like is there a better way of doing what I am doing?!

**P.S.** This is an example of genetic algorithm and I have the two arrays in `selected_parents` as the first generation parents. Now I want to apply crossover, which means: A cutting point (i.e. `co_point` in the code) which is a random integer between 1 and the parents length (herein 8), is selected randomly; the ﬁrst descendant (i.e. `crossed_p1`) inherits a longer substring from the ﬁrst parent and replaces the numbers of shorter substring in the order of numbers appeared in the second parent. And similar procedure is repeated for the second descendant (i.e. `crossed_p2`). For example, based on the current `selected_parents` list, and for a `co_point = 5`, the first descendant (i.e. `crossed_p1`) inherits the substring of `46310` from the ﬁrst parent, and the remaining substring of `752` is replaced by `275` which is the order of numbers appeared in the second parent. Hence, the first descendant (i.e. `crossed_p1`) is `46310275` and the second descendant (i.e. `crossed_p2`) will be `02735461`.

Comment: is there any reason why your vectors are 2D? One index `[0]` can be dropped if you would have 1D vectors: `selected_parents = 
[array([4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 2]), array([0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6])]`

Comment: And likewise, having `co_point` as an integer rather than a 1-element array would simplify things.

Comment: @rth They are built as 2D arrays through another process! Do you think if it is a good idea to define a new array as something like 1D_selected_parents = selected_parents[0] and work with that?

Comment: please use the appropriate tags. numpy is not the same as python

Comment: @hop just did; thanks for your constructive comment!

Comment: @Antonio I'm confused by your PS. Where you got replacement 275 there is no such string in the  the second parent in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the index is to elements of the `selected_parents` list, which are 2d arrays:

```
selected_parents[0][0][0:co_point[0]]
```

arrays can be indexed with one set of []:

```
selected_parents[0][0, 0:co_point[0]]
```

notationally it might be convenient to 'name' the 2 elements of the list (unpacking):

```
p1, p2 = selected_parents
p1[0, 0:co_point[0]]
```

Generally it is better to use `shape` than `len` on an array.  Replace

```
len(selected_parents[0][0])
```

with

```
p1.shape[1]
```

`p1.shape` is (1,8)

Looks like `p1, p2` have the same shape.  In which case

```
np.stack(selected_parents)
```

should produce a (2,1,8) array, which could be reshaped to (2,8).  Or

```
np.concatenate(selected_parents, axis=0)
```

producing a (2,8) array.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the simplest way to make a crossover if your gens are 1D lists:

```
>>> selected_parents = [[4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 2], [0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6]]
```

Let's create two parants, and selecet point of crossover:

```
>>> p1, p2 = selected_parents
>>> cx = random.randint(len(p1))
>>> p1
[4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 2]
>>> p2
[0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6]
>>> cx
4
```

First and second chlidrens are conjuctions of two tancated lists

```
>>> ch1=p1[:cx]+p2[cx:]
>>> ch1
[4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 4, 1, 6]
>>> ch2=p2[:cx]+p1[cx:]
>>> ch2
[0, 2, 7, 3, 0, 7, 5, 2]
>>>
```

If you need numpy, it is not a problem. The same idea below:

```
>>> selected_parents = [array([[4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 2]]), array([[0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6]])]
>>> p1, p2 = selected_parents
>>> p1
array([[4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 2]])
>>> p2
array([[0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 4, 1, 6]])
>>> cx = random.randint(p1.shape[1])
>>> cx
5
>>> ch1=append(p1[0][:cx],p2[0][cx:])
>>> ch1
array([4, 6, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1, 6])
>>> ch2=append(p2[0][:cx],p1[0][cx:])
>>> ch2
array([0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 7, 5, 2])
```

Comment: Well thanks for the response, but for the specific problem that I am solving, I need to apply crossover in the way I explained in the P.S.

Comment: As I stated, I'm confused by your example. My answer shows you a way to minimize indexes and loops. Hope you can adapt this style to your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized version of your code. One pleasant side effect of vectorization is that it often does away with most of the indices.

This code assumes that the parent vectors are shuffles of `0, 1, 2, ...`. If that's not the case some more work is needed:

```
def invperm(p):
    out = np.empty_like(p)
    idx = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, p.shape))]
    idx[-1] = p
    out[idx] = np.arange(p.shape[-1])
    return out

def f_pp(selected_parents):
    sp = np.reshape(selected_parents, (2, -1))
    _, N = sp.shape
    co = np.random.randint(0, N)
    out = sp.copy()
    slc = np.s_[:co] if 2*co < N else np.s_[co:]
    out[::-1, slc] = out[
        np.c_[:2], np.sort(invperm(sp)[np.c_[:2], sp[::-1, slc]], axis=1)]
    return out
```